# Wordpress sort posts by multiple meta values

Tags: wordpress, loops, metadata

i would like to sort my posts first by "time" meta value and secondly by "clicks" meta value.So if 2 posts have the same "time" the one with less clicks will go first.

```
     $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'players',
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'meta_key' => 'times',
    'posts_per_page'=> '15',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'offset' => $offsetnumber

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `posts_orderby` filter to customize the sql query to sort by multiple fields.

Some details here:

http://jeffgran.com/262/blog/wordpress-sort-posts-by-multiple-fields-part-ii

Comment: Not really helping,i'm looking for something to add in the query above

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with custom meta fields. I am pretty sure it is just for ordering the post table without consideration of the meta table.

Comment: I take that back. This can definitely work, it is about nailing down how to reference the meta. Not sure about to meta values, but this worked for meta value and then post title: `$orderby = "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC, $wpdb->posts.post_title ASC";`